# Get the data from fetch -> promise -> response

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am trying to post some data to the server but I don't know how to get back the response data.

I have the following code:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: login,
    password: password,
  })
}).then(function(a){
  console.log(a);
})
```

It prints a `Response` it contains data such as body (ReadableByteStream), bodyUsed (false), ok (true), status (200),...
but I cannot find the data I get back, nowhere. When I open the chrome developer console - network I see the response data there.

What am I doing wrong?

I've been looking for some resources how fetch, promises,... work but I couldn't find any well written.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetch Promise never gets executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005787/fetch-promise-never-gets-executed)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are further methods you call on a fetch response, such as `.json()`, or `.blob()`. These methods return a promise which you can call `.then()` on.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: login,
        password: password,
    })
})
    .then(function (a) {
        return a.json(); // call the json method on the response to get JSON
    })
    .then(function (json) {
        console.log(json)
    })
```

Check out [some documentation on using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), and some other documentation on how the [response object works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) in a fetch call.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns `Promise` which could be resolved to `Response` object that has several methods, like `text()`, `json()`, `blob()`, which also return `Promise` with `String` / `Object` / `Blob`.

So you have to resolve promises twice!!

```
fetch(...)
    .then((rsp) => rsp.json())
    .then((obj) => console.log(obj));
```